# Using Hahn-Banach theorem, can we extend an operator to have the same operator norm?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

[image]

Above is a theorem in p.74 of "Functional Analysis" by Peter Lax.

[image]

Above is theorem 8 of chapter 3.

***My question :***
Let $X$ be a normed linear space over the real or complex numbers and $Y$ be a subspace, $l$ be a bounded linear functional on $Y$.
If $l:Y\to\mathbb{C}$ has operator norm $C$, then can it be extended to $X$ so that the extension has the same operator norm as $l$?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Prove it for norm 1 first, then you can easily prove it for arbitrary norms.

Comment: The trick is to consider $p(x) := C \|x\|$ in the sublinear functional form of HBT (theorem 8 of Chapter 3).

Comment: @Math_QED, Rhys Steele  Thank you.